# How to use variables with RESTORE FILELISTONLY

Tags: sql-server, restore

Storing the result of RESTORE FILELISTONLY in a temporary table called #filepaths.

```
IF object_id('sp_restore') IS NOT NULL
    drop procedure sp_restore
    go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_restore AS
BEGIN
    RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak'
END
GO

insert into #filepaths 
exec sp_restore
```

How can I get 'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak' into a variable? So that the script looks similar to this.

```
DECLARE @BACKUP_PATH as nvarchar(max) = 'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak'

IF object_id('sp_restore') IS NOT NULL
    drop procedure sp_restore
    go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_restore AS
BEGIN
    RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @BACKUP_PATH
END
GO

insert into #filepaths 
exec sp_restore
```

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have things just a little messed up. How about:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_restore
  @backup_path NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @backup_path;
END
GO
```

Creating the procedure should be completely separate from any individual invocation. So in a different window, or two weeks later, you should be able to do this (again, completely separately from the creation of the stored procedure):

```
DECLARE @bp NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak';

INSERT #filepaths EXEC dbo.usp_restore @backup_path = @bp;
```

Some other commentary you should look into:

- [Why you shouldn't use the `sp_` prefix](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)
- [Why you should always use the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

---

If you don't want a stored procedure to help with this (why not?), sure you can do this in a much messier way. Assuming you already have a #temp table, `#t`, created with the right columns and data types:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak';

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @path;';

INSERT #t EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@path NVARCHAR(MAX)', @path;
```

But still, why not just have a stored procedure ready when you need it, instead of porting around all this bulky code?

Comment: Hello Aaron, I'm only using a CREATE PROCEDURE because I don't know how to get the contents of RESTORE FILELISTONLY into a table without an SP. Is there a way to avoid using a stored procedure all together?

Answer (score -1):

When your script hits that first `GO`, your batch ends and your variable goes out of scope.

From the GO [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> SQL Server utilities interpret GO as a signal that they should send
>   the current batch of Transact-SQL statements to an instance of SQL
>   Server. The current batch of statements is composed of all statements
>   entered since the last GO, or since the start of the ad hoc session or
>   script if this is the first GO.

So when the second batch is sent over (where you use RESTORE FILELISTONLY), those variables and their values are not included.

Comment: A small link to the documentation would be very nice.

Comment: @From Review – Philᵀᴹ I presented an answer.  It may be right or wrong, but it was definitely an answer.  Can you explain?

Answer (score -3):

I think you can only do this with dynamic SQL. Replace the body of your SP with the following:

```
DECLARE @BACKUP_PATH as nvarchar(max) = 'Z:\BACKUPS\my_database_backup.bak'

IF object_id('sp_restore') IS NOT NULL
    drop procedure sp_restore
    go

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_restore AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SQL = 'RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @BACKUP_PATH  + '''

  EXEC SP_ExecuteSql @SQLToExecute

END
GO

insert into #filepaths 
exec sp_restore
```

Comment: No, dynamic SQL is not necessary, and this still doesn't work (that variable is not in scope inside the procedure, and not just because of the `go`).

Comment: =+ [it has a bad practice of avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). I am not downvoting though .. just highlighting obvious stuff.

Comment: I need to stop resorting to dynamic SQL by default

Comment: As it turns out, dynamic SQL might be required here, but not for the reason you thought. :-)

Comment: Is that for the 2nd question?

Comment: No, see the comment on my answer.